# Open Developer Page in Mac App Store on macOS Mojave

Tags: mac-app-store, macos-mojave

the new Mac App Store offers a Developer Page.
I would like to link to this page from within my apps.

How can do this? I know that I can open single apps (the Mac App Store even shows a "Copy Link" option), but the developer page does not have this option.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, you can manually award the bounty to me (this is my first time getting it) :D

Comment: I have to wait 23 hours to award it.

Comment: No problem mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

- You have to get your developer ID. You can find this by using the homepage www.fnd.io (search for developers, click the link to your developer page and the URL will contain your developer id).
- Create your "short name" by using the rules posted by @AngusTay

Now use this information and insert it into the following URL:

```
macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/<short name>/id<your developer id>?mt=8#
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

For what I know, you can do it manually by using the [**Apple Linkmaker**](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us), assuming your developer referring to your 'company'.

The Standard App Store Links: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8

These URLs are great for linking to your app or company page in the App Store or Mac App Store from your website or inside your app, or anywhere you don't need to type or speak the URL. As a rule, always use these standard links when driving users to your app from your digital marketing communications.

You can also create easy-to-read links to your app using App Store Short Links, which use the AppStore.com base URL plus a specific form of your app or company name.

There are three types of App Store Short Links, in two forms, one for iOS apps, another for Mac Apps:

**Company Name**

iOS: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/apple

Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/ for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple

**App Name**

iOS: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/keynote

Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/ for example, http://appstore.com/mac/keynote

**App by Company**

iOS: http://appstore.com// for example, http://appstore.com/apple/keynote

Mac: http://appstore.com/mac// for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple/keynote

Most companies and apps have a canonical App Store Short Link. This canonical URL is created by changing or removing certain characters (many of which are illegal or have special meaning in a URL (for example, "&")).

To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your company or app name:

1. Remove all whitespace
2. Convert all characters to lower-case
3. Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
4. Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
5. Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
6. Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
7. Leave all other characters as-is.

Answer source: [Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1633/_index.html)

Comment: Just a quick update, the links no longer work on macOS Mojave since Beta 11.

Comment: @SaschaSimon I thought the LinkMaker is still working?

Comment: When typing http://appstore.com/mac/apple in Safari, previously the Mac App Store opened and a search was started. Since a couple of days, this no longer works. The "Loading" bar is shown in the Mac App Store, but a timeout occurs.