# How to display all apps of developer in the brand new macOS Mojave App Store?

Tags: macos, app-store, mac-app-store, macos-mojave, nsworkspace

I am displaying all my macOS apps in App Store by a single line like this:

```
NSString *finalLink = @"http://appstore.com/mac/JiulongZhao"
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalLink]];
```

It works until macOS Mojave 10.14. the webpage jumps but App Store just hanging there or "Cannot Connect to App Store".
BTW, the visit of each app is still available like this:

```
NSString *finalLink = @"macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/Overlay/id653092846"
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalLink]];
```

Any advice?

Yes, a statement in browser like this is still working:

```
macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/Overlay/id653092846
```

The following recommended answer does not work well, I will upload my answer soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Developer Page in Mac App Store on macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081440/open-developer-page-in-mac-app-store-on-macos-mojave)

Answer (score 0):

The following link works to open all apps made by Apple on the Mojave Mac App Store:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/apple/id284417353?mt=12&uo=4&at=11l6hc&app=itunes&ct=fnd

Found via the links created by the `fnd.io` tool:

https://fnd.io/#/us/search?mediaType=all&term=Apple

Suggested in the accepted answer here:

[Open Developer Page in Mac App Store on macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081440/open-developer-page-in-mac-app-store-on-macos-mojave)